# JSP exception implicit object

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, exception

I have a little Java web application. It uses MVC, with a `HttpServlet` as controller and several JSPs for view.

The Servlet captures several exceptions like SQLExceptions, and I need process these exceptions  in an "ErrorPage" JSP. (JSP with directive `<%@page isErrorPage="true" %>`.)
The problem is, How can I set "exception" JSP implicit object from the Servlet?

(I'm using a RequestDispatcher object to pass control to error page.)

Comment: see below my response for how to configure and use the error page and making use of JSP implicit exception.

Answer (score 2):

This is the usage,

**page1.jsp**

```
<%@page errorPage="errorpage.jsp" %>
<%
  //this has your code that throws some exception

%>
```

The exception thrown in jsp page will be caught based on your errorPage configuration.

**errorpage.jsp**

```
<%@ page isErrorPage='true' %>
<%
out.print("Error Message : ");  
out.print(exception.getMessage());
%>
```

The exception object represents all errors and exceptions. The exception implicit object is of type java.langThrowable. You can access the exception object on a page that you declare to be an error page using the isErrorPage attribute of the page directive.

The exception object is created only if the JSP uses the page directive to set `isErrorPage` set to true. When a JSP generates an error and forwards that error to the error page, the container sets the JSP exception object of the error page to the generated error

Apart from `exception.getMessage()`, you can also invoke `printStackTrace()` and `toString()` on `exception` object.

Is this what you were asking? or you want to handle exception in your Servlet class?

Also, If you configure your web.xml like this ,

```
<error-page>  
   <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>  
   <location>/errorpage.jsp</location>  
</error-page>
```

then for all exceptions this error page is invoked, and you can use the `exception` object as mentioned above and invoke its methods for the exception details.
If you want to configure a specific error page for a specific exception, change the `<exception-type>` accordingly

Note that the exception is set by container when it encounters an exception. If you just forward the control to your error page, it just displays the page.

**updated:**

```
try {
//sample code
    data= dao.find(something);
}
catch (SQLException e) {
    throw new ServletException("The query got failed", e);
}
```

The Servlet container handles the ServletException . When the container catch it while executing the servlet, then its cause will be unwrapped and compared against any of the specific  entries in web.xml and the closest match will be displayed.

```
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.sql.SQLException</exception-type>
    <location>/errorpage.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

**Update 2**

*To give another example:*

**web.xml**

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>servlet1</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.examples.example.Servlet1</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>servlet1</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<error-page>
    <exception-type>javax.servlet.ServletException</exception-type>
    <location>/errorpage.jsp</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.sql.SQLException</exception-type>
    <location>/errorpage.jsp</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
    <location>/errorpage.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

**Servlet1.java**

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            String s = null;
            if (s.equals("")) {

            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new ServletException("my custom exception message");
        }
    }
```

**errorpage.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" isErrorPage='true'%>
<html>
<head>
<title>Error Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <%
        out.print("Error Message : ");
        out.print(exception.getMessage());
    %>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, for your response. I know that operation. But in my case, the exception is catched in a Servlet, and I want to manage it in JSP error page.

Comment: I wonder why you want yo do it that way.if you are able to catch the exception in the servlet then why do u want to handle it again in jsp? Not recommended but you can set the exception object as a request attribute and forward to errorpage. You can get the attribute which is exception object in jsp. But this is nothing related to errorpage default configuration

Comment: If yoy are catching in servlet, then managing in jsp doesn't seem valid

Comment: Thank you for your comments. The idea is to use a JSP ErrorPage if it's possible. @prash: HttpServlet methods throws only "ServletException" and "IOException", isn't it?

Comment: or is this you want to try out ? `try { ...} catch (SQLException ex) {
throw new ServletException(ex);}`

Comment: Please note that the Servlet container handles teh flow to error page , not the developer by routing using "RequestDispatcher object to pass control to error page".

Comment: Thank you, prash! It works throwing  ServletException and then the container catched it by mean deployment descriptor with <exception-type> tag to pass control to JSP page.

Comment: Please mark as answer if it helped and you feel the same

Comment: Yes that's it.  Glad to hear. I too tried out before posting